# Sorting dataframe string by string

Tags: r

I have a dataframe containing several rows with pairs in this format

```
41,25
25,41
23,41
41,23
```

I only want pairs that are distinct and the order doesn't matter.
So for example the dataframe should look like this instead

```
41,25
41,25
41,23
41,23
```

So I can count how many times the combination 41 and 25 occures.

So I want to run through the whole dataframe and sort each string so the highest values comes first.(or lowest, doesn't matter).

Hope for you help. I'm guessing it's pretty simple, but can't figure it out.

Thanks

Comment: I assume you have a character column with this data then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be embarrassing when seen against the slick coding of @Matthew Plourde, but I don't think you wanted to remove duplicate rows, so here is the solution I came up with:

```
#Make some data
set.seed(1)
N <- 200
MIN <- 1
MAX <- 8
df <- data.frame(x=paste(round(runif(N, min=MIN, max=MAX)), round(runif(N, min=MIN, max=MAX)), sep=","))

#Split data into 2 components
require(plyr)
tmp <- ldply(strsplit(as.character(df$x), ","))
df$x1 <- as.numeric(tmp[,1])
df$x2 <- as.numeric(tmp[,2])
head(df)

#sort smaller of values to the left
tmp <- t(apply(df[,2:3], 1, sort))
df$x.sort <- apply(tmp, 1, paste, collapse=",")
head(df)

#sort df
ord <- order(df$x.sort)
df <- df[ord,]
head(df, 20)
```

Which results in:

```
      x x1 x2 x.sort
167 1,1  1  1    1,1
92  1,2  1  2    1,2
27  1,3  1  3    1,3
71  3,1  3  1    1,3
28  4,1  4  1    1,4
47  1,4  1  4    1,4
55  1,4  1  4    1,4
67  4,1  4  1    1,4
81  4,1  4  1    1,4
116 1,4  1  4    1,4
133 1,4  1  4    1,4
152 5,1  5  1    1,5
10  1,6  1  6    1,6
85  6,1  6  1    1,6
99  7,1  7  1    1,7
109 7,1  7  1    1,7
5   2,2  2  2    2,2
12  2,2  2  2    2,2
22  2,2  2  2    2,2
56  2,2  2  2    2,2
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm

Answer (score 3):

If `d` is your `data.frame` and the pairs are strings in one column, then

```
d[, 1] <- sapply(strsplit(d[, 1], ','), function(x) paste(sort(x), collapse=','))
```

If the pairs are split between two columns, say columns 1 and 2, then

```
d[, 1:2] <- t(apply(apply(d[, 1:2], 1, identity), 2, sort))
```